# How to check with regex does url contain WWW?

Tags: web, url

I need to chceck if the Url contains a WWW. What is regex for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for "normal" characters within a regex, you simply search for those characters. You don't need any sort of special characters.

For example:

```
echo "www.google.com" | egrep --color 'www'
www.google.com
```

Comment: No I need regex for c# AddRedirect method.First parameter is regex that check does url contains that you need